# Best approach to assigning constructors objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor, coding-style

I am receiving from the server an array of objects:

```
[{name: 'Al'}, {name: 'Ann'}]
```

I'd like to convert these to a *Person* constructor I created. Right now I am doing this:

```
  function Person(attributes) {
    angular.extend(this, attributes);
    return this;
  }

  Person.prototype.getName = function() {
    return "My name is " + this.name;
  }

  $scope.people = [];

  $http.get('people')
  .success(function(people) {
    $scope.people = people.map(function(person, i) {
      return new Person(person);
    });
  });
```

Can anyone think of a better approach? One that would not require having to convert each of the objects inside my array to the desired constructor? Perhaps a way to tell my array that all objects within it are instances of Person at all times. Or maybe I can include the getName method to the $scope.people array and somehow have the objects within it call the method located in its parent array...

Also if there is a way I can convert the object to a constructor (along with its prototype methods) without using angular.extend as i did in my example that would be nice. thanks.

Comment: What about writing `Person.map()` as a wrapper to do this for you?

Comment: Your solution seems fine to me. Did you benchmark this and found it out to be a bottleneck or asking out of curiosity?

Comment: Any method would eventually have to call ```new Person()``` at some level.